# Additional view not working as expected

Tags: django-rest-framework

I added a decorated method on my ModelViewSet. It's not working as I expect. I can browse to "/customers/1/add", but "/customers/1/add/1" returns a 404. Why?

```py
from rest_framework import routers, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from app1.models import Customer

class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Customer

    @action()
    def add(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'customers', CustomerViewSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `@action` and `@link` decorators, you can include extra urls for basic routing, [as stated in the docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html#marking-extra-methods-for-routing).

At the end of the docs it mentions that the views can be accessed at `resource/:id/method/`:

> The two new actions will then be available at the urls ^users/{pk}/set_password/$ and ^users/{pk}/unset_password/$
>
> -- [Django Request Frameworks docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html#marking-extra-methods-for-routing)

This is [hardcoded into the router](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L106).